# Get the HTML trademark symbol as dropdown text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to bind the registered symbol to the drop down as a text .
I want to add `"sample text &reg;"` as the master data in the sql tables , and when I bind the value to dropdown it should display `"sample text ®" .`

I have tried them now , but it is binding as html encoded .The & is itself getting converted to another html code when rendered by the browser .

Is there any other way around this ?

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to display trade mark symbol as dropdown text

```html
    <select class="form-control">
        <option> <text> My Text &trade; </text> </option>
    </select>
```